# Getting '401 unauthorized' when trying to send a GET request to systeminfo.xml

Tags: python, rest, iis, request

I want to get the configuration of devices on my XProtect Corporate account, I am following this post

http://doc.developer.milestonesys.com/html/reference/protocols/imageserver_getdevices.html

but I am getting 401, unauthorized every time.

Until now I have managed to authenticate myself and got a token, now as i have the corporate account, I will need to send the token for the authorization, I am using requests lib in python to send a GET request like this

```
head = {'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(myToken)}

response = requests.get('http://server-ip/rcserver/sysmteminfo.xml', headers=head)

print response
```

I am not sure about how to send my token in this get request

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should set auth dictionary to pass in requests.get. Did you try it?

Comment: didn't get you @FedericoRubbi

Comment: I've read the post you linked. I assume you have credentials for that site, isn't it?

Comment: yes, I have a valid token

Comment: Hmm... could you try to add these headers: {'Content-Length': '0', 'Host': 'xprotectserver.company.com'} and set allow_redirect=True and timeout=10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally able to get the configuration of all the devices on the server. Problem was, the above approach works for XProtect Enterprise and XProtect Professional only, if you have an XProtect Corporate, you need a NTLM authentication and you have to call GetConfiguration function on the Server SOAP protocol.

```
r2= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetConfiguration xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand"><token>' + str(myToken) + '</token></GetConfiguration></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
data_len = str(len(r2))
s.sendall("POST /ManagementServer/ServerCommandService.svc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server-ip\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nAuthorization: Basic (base64 encoded '*[BASIC]\username:password*')\r\nContent-Length: "+data_len+"\r\nSOAPAction: http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand/IServerCommandService/GetConfiguration\r\n\r\n"+ r2)
```